# Upper bound for complex characteristic function

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

I am trying to get why the following holds for $X$ real random variable with distribution $F$:

$$|\int e^{itx} dF| \leq e^{|t^2|/2} \int e^{x^2/2} dF$$

Let $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x$ real. We have $$2|tx|\leq |x^2| + |t^2|.$$

$$| \int e^{itx} dF | \leq \int |e^{itx}| dF$$

I can then write $t=a+bi$ and get to
$$\leq \int e^{-bx} dF.$$

How do I get the absolute value into the exponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t=a+ib$, $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Then $-2xb \leq x^{2}+b^{2} \leq x^{2}+a^{2}+b^{2}$. Now LHS $\leq \int e^{-xb}dF(x) \leq \int e^{(x^{2}+a^{2}+b^{2})/2}dF(x)$ from which the inequality follows.